# Unexpected Parameter: id on my python jupyter code

Tags: python

i had build code to sentiment analysis using python, my code was like this :

```
import tweepy
api_key = "sdlksadksa;ldksald"
api_secret_key = "sakdlas,mcsdmv,dlv"
access_token = "alskdklamlas"
access_token_secret = "salkdjklmclqm"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

hasilUser = api.user_timeline(id="jokowi" , count = 10)
```

in case to you guys know, my `api_key` until `access_token_secret` are dummy and not the real one.

when i run `hasilUser` idk why it turn like this

```
Unexpected parameter: id
```

i had no idea what is going on and what should i do

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [Tweepy docs](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/)? Are you sure the [`user_timeline`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.user_timeline) method expects an `id` parameter?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnI6F_F11Xk i watch this video on 6:24 and idk why he can input ```id```

Comment: That video's from a year ago, maybe it changed with a newer version of Tweepy. If something like that doesn't work, the documentation is a good place to look first.

Answer (score 1):

I think input parameters of API.user_timeline changed(may be from `id` to `user_id`).

You can see the actual parameters of it in the code below, 530th line.

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py

```
    @pagination(mode='id')
    @payload('status', list=True)
    def user_timeline(self, **kwargs):
        """user_timeline(*, user_id, screen_name, since_id, count, max_id, \
                         trim_user, exclude_replies, include_rts)
        Returns the 20 most recent statuses posted from the authenticating user
        or the user specified. It's also possible to request another user's
        timeline via the id parameter.
        Parameters
        ----------
        user_id
            |user_id|
        screen_name
            |screen_name|
        since_id
            |since_id|
        count
            |count|
        max_id
            |max_id|
        trim_user
            |trim_user|
        exclude_replies
            |exclude_replies|
        include_rts
            When set to ``false``, the timeline will strip any native retweets
            (though they will still count toward both the maximal length of the
            timeline and the slice selected by the count parameter). Note: If
            you're using the trim_user parameter in conjunction with
            include_rts, the retweets will still contain a full user object.
        Returns
        -------
        :py:class:`List`\[:class:`~tweepy.models.Status`]
        References
        ----------
        https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline
        """
        return self.request(
            'GET', 'statuses/user_timeline', endpoint_parameters=(
                'user_id', 'screen_name', 'since_id', 'count', 'max_id',
                'trim_user', 'exclude_replies', 'include_rts'
            ), **kwargs
        )
```